# Failed to load resource - server responded with a 404 status error in Rails 3 project

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to load up jquery masonry script in my app, but it's not working.

Upon debugging, I see this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a http://localhost:3000/app/assets/javascripts/jquery.masonry.min.js status of 404 (Not Found)
```

If I try to access the script directly from my browser via the link http://localhost:3000/app/assets/javascripts/jquery.masonry.min.js I get this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/Users/fkhalid2008/loand/app/assets/javascripts/jquery.masonry.min.js"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Relevant code is attached below.

Thanks,

Faisal

**POSTS>INDEX.HTML.ERB (This is where I am trying to load up the Jquery Masonry script)**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/app/assets/javascripts/jquery.masonry.min.js">     
</script>

.....

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('#container').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.box',
   columnWidth : 120 
});
</script>
```

**APPLICATION.JS FILE**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.masonry.min
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with assets pipeline, you just need tell the Rails app that the file its in you asset folder. Like:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
```

And put the jquery.masonry.min.js at /app/assets/javascripts

Comment: I made the change you suggested, and now get an error that says 'Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" with reference to the Masonry.js

Answer (score 0):

your source for the jquery API is incorrect - it is looking in a local directory, but it appears as if you are trying to use google APIs

Comment: no, the first one is fine, its the second one (masonry.js) that isn't working. i am trying to source that (i.e. masonry.js) through a local directory.

Comment: so the 404 is referencing the masonry js? The full error is truncated in your post

Comment: i just updated the error message...yes, the 404 error references just the masonry js file